# Split data by levels in hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Example of initial data:

```
| ID   |  ParentID  |
|------|------------|
|  1   |    NULL    |
|  2   |     1      |
|  3   |     1      |
|  4   |     2      |
|  5   |    NULL    |
|  6   |     2      |
|  7   |     3      |
```

In my initial data I have ID of element and his parent ID. 
Some elements has parent, some has not, some has a parent and his parent has a parent.

The maximum number of levels in this hierarchy is 3.

I need to get this hierarchy by levels.

`Lvl 1` - elements without parents
`Lvl 2` - elements with parent which doesn't have parent
`Lvl 3` - elements with parent which has a parent too.

Expected result looks like:

```
| Lvl1  |   Lvl2   |   Lvl3   |
|-------|----------|----------|
|  1    |   NULL   |   NULL   |
|  1    |    2     |   NULL   |
|  1    |    3     |   NULL   |
|  1    |    2     |    4     |
|  5    |   NULL   |   NULL   |
|  1    |    2     |    6     |
|  1    |    3     |    7     |
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Do you ***know*** for ***certain*** that you need to go to a maximum depth of lvl3, and this ***won't*** change?  If it's flexible/dynamic/variable then this is generally not a good idea, and the question becomes; why do you want to do this, what will you use it for?  There are probably better alternatives, SQL likes the normalised structure that you're starting from.

Comment: @MatBailie I need this view only for report, yes, maximum depth will not change and it will be always 3.

Comment: Even for reporting, this is often the wrong direction.  You may be better served by asking a question about how to write an example report.  Show us the data you'll start with, show us the final report you want, tell us what reporting application you'll be using, and then we can help find the appropriate pattern, rather than "just" show you how to implement what is often an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fixed dept of three, you can use `CROSS APPLY`.

It can be used like a `JOIN`, but also return extra records to give you the `NULL`s.

```
SELECT
  Lvl1.ID   AS lvl1,
  Lvl2.ID   AS lvl2,
  Lvl3.ID   AS lvl3
FROM
  initial_data   AS Lvl1
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT ID FROM initial_data WHERE ParentID = Lvl1.ID
   UNION ALL
   SELECT NULL AS ID
)
  AS Lvl2
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT ID FROM initial_data WHERE ParentID = Lvl2.ID
   UNION ALL
   SELECT NULL AS ID
)
  AS Lvl3
WHERE
  Lvl1.ParentID IS NULL
ORDER BY
  Lvl1.ID,
  Lvl2.ID,
  Lvl3.ID
```

But, as per my comment, this is often a sign that you're headed down a non-sql route.  It might feel easier to start with, but later it turns and bites you, because SQL benefits tremendously from normalised structures (your starting data).

Comment: Thanks, it works, but also many thanks for the detailed explanation about the bad practice of this decision.